# OpenCV with stdcall

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use OpenCV in a project that has a default calling convention of stdcall. However, openCV by default uses cdecl and there doesn't seem to be a macro that allows me to change this behavior easily.

Short of adding an explicit `__stdcall` in the header files for all the functions/classes that I have to use, is there an easier way to change this behavior?

I found this [link](http://code.opencv.org/issues/922) (it's quite old), where someone faced a similar issue but resorted to changing the default calling convention of their project.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I tried building OpenCV myself and changing the calling convention in the project files, but it fails to compile with > 1000 errors

Comment: What platform / compiler are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, 32 bit Windows

Comment: You can set the default calling convention in the C++ settings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx  This will only work assuming you're compiling the openCV libs yourself / along with your project.

Comment: I have already tried that (changing the opencv project to use stdcall). OpenCV does not like it however, and a million errors pop up about redefinitions with different type modifiers and "cant convert from void (__stdcall*) (const void*) to int(__cdecl*)(const void*)"

Comment: Sounds very crude, but can you try a find and replace `__cdecl` with `__stdcall` in the folder where the OpenCV files are? Think it might cause more problems but might be worth a try.